# Limit query results in laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I am trying to limit the results of this query:

```
$gallery = Event::with('EventsMedia')->orderBy('start', 'desc')->get();
```

currently it shows all the events with their images. What i want is to show only 3 results. I tried writting it like this:

```
$gallery = DB::table('events')
               ->join('events_media', 'events.id', '=','events_media.events_id')
               ->orderBy('start', 'desc')
               ->take(4)
               ->get();
```

But my events and their images ended up not showing at all.

Please advise.

Comment: What was wrong with just `Event::with('EventsMedia')->orderBy('start', 'desc')->take(3)->get();`

Comment: Why would you switch from Eloquent to the DB facade? you can use the `take(3)` on the first code too.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you had to change the query. You could've simply written it like this, just by adding `limit(4)` in the end:

```
$gallery = Event::with('EventsMedia')->orderBy('start', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use relations query builder.

```
$gallery = Event::with('EventsMedia', function($query) {
    $query->limit(3)
})->orderBy('start', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Works but more complicated than it needs to be, there is no need for the closure, the `->limit(3)` can simply be invoked directly after `orderBy`, or am I missing something?